# Doubts about symbolic link Printer Brother all-in-one

Tags: udev

I have a doubt and confusion regarding symlinks on settings of "Brother MFC-660CN printer"

I installed the drivers through an installation file of the website Brother

The file is "linux-1.0-installer-brfax"

Installed everything right without errors ...

But in the **/var/log/sys.log** or on **boot** appear this:

```
FX6300 udevd[412]: unknown key 'SYSFS{idVendor}' in /etc/udev/rules.d/40-brother-libsane-type1.rules:17
FX6300 udevd[412]: invalid rule '/etc/udev/rules.d/40-brother-libsane-type1.rules:17'
```

In the file **/etc/udev/rules.d/40-brother-libsane-type1.rules** i have this:

```
> #   udev rules sample for Brother MFP
> #         version 1.0.0-1
> #
> #   Copyright (C) 2012 Brother. Industries, Ltd.
> #
> #   copy to /etc/udev/rules.d or /lib/udev/rules.d
> #
> 
>
> ACTION!="add", GOTO="brother_mfp_end"
> 
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", GOTO="brother_mfp_udev_1" SUBSYSTEM!="usb_device",
> GOTO="brother_mfp_end" LABEL="brother_mfp_udev_1"
> 
>
> SYSFS{idVendor}=="04f9", GOTO="brother_mfp_udev_2"
> ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", GOTO="brother_mfp_udev_2"
> GOTO="brother_mfp_end" LABEL="brother_mfp_udev_2"
> 
> #  ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="01", GOTO="brother_mfp_udev_3"
> #  ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="02", GOTO="brother_mfp_udev_3"
> #  ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="03", GOTO="brother_mfp_udev_3"
> #  GOTO="brother_mfp_end"
> #  LABEL="brother_mfp_udev_3"
> 
> ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}!="0ff", GOTO="brother_mfp_end"
> ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}!="0ff", GOTO="brother_mfp_end"
> ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}!="0ff", GOTO="brother_mfp_end"
> 
> #MODE="0666"
> #GROUP="scanner" ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
> #SYMLINK+="scanner-%k"
> 
> LABEL="brother_mfp_end"
```

In the file **/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules**:

```
# Kernel < 2.6.22 jumps here
LABEL="libsane_usb_rules_begin"

# Brother scanners
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="01b0", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"

# The following rule will disable USB autosuspend for the device
ENV{libsane_matched}=="yes", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'if test -e /sys/$env{DEVPATH}/power/control; then echo on > /sys/$env{DEVPATH}/power/control; elif test -e /sys/$env{DEVPATH}/power/level; then echo on > /sys/$env{DEVPATH}/power/level; fi'"

LABEL="libsane_usb_rules_end"
```

When i install anything from terminal i have this error too:

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libbrcolm2.so.1 is not a symbolic link
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libbrscandec2.so.1 is not a symbolic link
```

When i use the **ls -l** command i have this:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/libbrscandec2.so
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 37064 Nov 23 18:21 /usr/lib/libbrscandec2.so

$ ls -l /usr/lib/libbrscandec2.so.1
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 37064 Nov 23 18:21 /usr/lib/libbrscandec2.so.1

$ ls -l /usr/lib/libbrscandec2.so.1.0.0
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 37064 Nov 23 18:21 /usr/lib/libbrscandec2.so.1.0.0

$ ls -l /usr/lib64/libbrscandec2.so
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Dez  2  2009 /usr/lib64/libbrscandec2.so -> /usr/lib64/libbrscandec2.so.1

$ ls -l /usr/lib64/libbrscandec2.so.1
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Dez  2  2009 /usr/lib64/libbrscandec2.so.1 -> /usr/lib64/libbrscandec2.so.1.0.0

$ ls -l /usr/lib64/libbrscandec2.so.1.0.0
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 37064 Dez  2  2009 /usr/lib64/libbrscandec2.so.1.0.0

$ ls -l /usr/lib/libbrcolm2.so
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 15072 Nov 23 18:21 /usr/lib/libbrcolm2.so

$ ls -l /usr/lib/libbrcolm2.so.1
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 15072 Nov 23 18:21 /usr/lib/libbrcolm2.so.1

$ ls -l /usr/lib/libbrcolm2.so.1.0.1
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 15072 Nov 23 18:21 /usr/lib/libbrcolm2.so.1.0.1

$ ls -l /usr/lib64/libbrcolm2.so
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Dez  2  2009 /usr/lib64/libbrcolm2.so -> /usr/lib64/libbrcolm2.so.1

$ ls -l /usr/lib64/libbrcolm2.so.1
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Dez  2  2009 /usr/lib64/libbrcolm2.so.1 -> /usr/lib64/libbrcolm2.so.1.0.1

$ ls -l /usr/lib64/libbrcolm2.so.1.0.1
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 15072 Dez  2  2009 /usr/lib64/libbrcolm2.so.1.0.1
```

I do not know if is the correct way that i think but ..

In the folder:

**/usr/lib64/**

The symbolic link is from:

**libbrscandec2.so** to **libbrscandec2.so.1** and ends in **libbrscandec2.so.1.0.0** ?

The same for **libbcolm2.so** ?

From what I've understood from other posts the symbolic link are to be between the folders:

**/usr/lib/** and **/usr/lib64/**

Or am i thinking in the wrong way?
 
What's wrong here?

I appreciate any help on this..

Thanks.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem...

I make a comment **/etc/udev/rules.d/40-brother-libsane-type1.rules**:

```
#SYSFS{idVendor}=="04f9", GOTO="brother_mfp_udev_2"  <<<<< here
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", GOTO="brother_mfp_udev_2"
GOTO="brother_mfp_end" LABEL="brother_mfp_udev_2"
```

Maybe a conflit between **SYSFS{idVendor}** and **ATTRS{idVendor}** since they are the same **"04f9"** ?? Just guessing...

And simlink in the **/etc/lib/**

**libbrscandec2.so > libbrscandec2.so.1 > libbrscandec2.so.1.0.0**

And to **libbcolm2.so** also like **libbrscanedc2.so**

The erros don't appear anymore...

Works really well...

Comment: Could you accept it as this solved your own answer?

Comment: Please click **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I started getting the same ldconfig symlink errors after upgrading to saucy.  You can manually edit the symlinks as [lc1975](https://askubuntu.com/users/218936/lc1975) did, or just remove and reinstall the *brscan2* package (available [here](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public/us/us/en/dlf/download_index.html?reg=us&c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc7220_us_as&dlid=&flang=English&os=128&type2=-1)).

Both libbrscandec2 and libbrcolm2 are provided by the *brscan2* deb from Brother, and they are symlinks in the package:

```
$ dpkg-deb -c brscan2-0.2.5-1.amd64.deb 
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2009-12-01 20:20 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/local/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/local/Brother/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/local/Brother/sane/
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1536 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/local/Brother/sane/Brsane2.ini
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/local/Brother/sane/GrayCmData/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/local/Brother/sane/GrayCmData/AL/
-rw-r--r-- root/root     14940 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/local/Brother/sane/GrayCmData/AL/brmsl09f.cm
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/local/Brother/sane/GrayCmData/ALL/
-rw-r--r-- root/root     14940 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/local/Brother/sane/GrayCmData/ALL/brmsl08f.cm
-rwxr-xr-x root/root     22312 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/local/Brother/sane/brsaneconfig2
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/local/Brother/sane/models2/
-rw-r--r-- root/root        98 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/local/Brother/sane/models2/ext2.ini
-rw-r--r-- root/root       722 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/local/Brother/sane/models2/ext1.ini
-rwxr-xr-x root/root       581 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/local/Brother/sane/setupSaneScan2
-rw-rw-rw- root/root         1 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/local/Brother/sane/brsanenetdevice2.cfg
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/lib64/
-rwxr-xr-x root/root     37064 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/lib64/libbrscandec2.so.1.0.0
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/lib64/sane/
-rwxr-xr-x root/root    112832 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother2.so.1.0.7
-rwxr-xr-x root/root     15072 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/lib64/libbrcolm2.so.1.0.1
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/bin/
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/lib64/libbrcolm2.so -> /usr/lib64/libbrcolm2.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/lib64/libbrscandec2.so.1 -> /usr/lib64/libbrscandec2.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/lib64/libbrscandec2.so -> /usr/lib64/libbrscandec2.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/lib64/libbrcolm2.so.1 -> /usr/lib64/libbrcolm2.so.1.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother2.so.1 -> /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother2.so.1.0.7
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother2.so -> /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother2.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2009-12-01 20:20 ./usr/bin/brsaneconfig2 -> /usr/local/Brother/sane/brsaneconfig2
```