# Error during update : /usr/lib/libbrcolm2.so.1 is not a symbolic link

Tags: command-line, apt, updates, symbolic-link

Hope you can help me I am using Ubuntu 18.04 (64bit) and I am a Newbie so please answer in layman terms.
When I do `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt update` I get the following message at the end:

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
/sbin/config.real: /usr/lib/libbrscandec2.so.1 is not a symbolic link
/sbin/config.real: /usr/lib/libbrcolm2.so.1 is not a symbolic link
```

Please can you tell me:

1. how this affects the system?
2. How to correct this?
3. What it means?

I am new to this forum so thanks in advance for helping me.
Frances

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu. Do you have a Brother printer or scanner? the error seems to be related to this: [Doubts about symbolic link Printer Brother all-in-one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/381659/doubts-about-symbolic-link-printer-brother-all-in-one)

Comment: Yes a Brother MFC-J6930DW. I also mislead you sorry the version I am using is Ubuntu 18.04 (I forgot I updated duh!) I had a look at the link you shared but I'm not sure what to do as the answers are a little advanced for me. I installed via the Brother site using their instructions.

Comment: Yes a Brother MFC-J6930DW. I had a look at the link you shared but I'm not sure what to do as the answers are a little advanced for me. I installed via the Brother site using their instructions.

Comment: Same issue. I also use a brother printer.